# Is the memory allocated to all the strings in the switch block?

Tags: java, memory-management, java-native-interface, switch-statement

```
case k_A:
  jstring a  = "....";
  break;
case k_B:
  jstring b = "....";
  break;
case k_C:
  jstring c = ".....";
  break;
case k_D:
  jstring d = ".....";
  break;
default:
  jstring dflt = ".....";
```

There are actually 200 case statements in my *case*. While only one case statement works at a time ,is the memory allocated to all the 201 statements in the switch block ? If yes,is this method recommended ?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth i mean will the compiler allocate each one of them a piece of memory ?

Comment: What's your *actual* code?  Are you really assigning a C string constant to a `jstring`?  Or is `"....."` a call to `NewStringUTF`?

Comment: @Edward Thomson a call to newstringutf, The answer by _bohemian_ will differ under jni ?

Answer (score 2):

The string literals all exist statically. Where do you think they magically appear from? In this case it is C so they all exists in your data segment.

If your case values are adjacent you should probably use a lookup array instead of a switch statement

However your code has other problems. C literals are not jstrings. You need to call NewStringUTF().

Comment: does this answer differ for java

Answer (score 0):

Memory is allocated for all the string literals **once** per JVM start.

The reason is due to [String interning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning): String literals are effectively compiled into the bytecode as special constants, and memory is allocated for all of them when the class loads, and never again.

Although the code appears to allocate memory with every call of the method, it doesn't - the JVM recycles these String objects, which is safe to do so, because String is [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object).

That's why this code works:

```
String a = "foo";
String b = "foo";
boolean same = (a == b); // true - they are the SAME object!
```

Don't worry about the memory usage - leave the code as it is.

Comment: so will i have to delete each reference ony by one

Comment: @assylias Thank you - string *literals*. Answer edited thusly.

Comment: @program-o-steve You *can't* delete the reference. It's handled internally by the String class. Just leave it. 200 string literals is nothing, unless you're writing code to run on a very, very small environment

Comment: I doubt that string literals in arbitrary c modules are interned.. how exactly would that work? The literals itself are allocated by the compiler in the data segment though so you don't have to (need not!) fee them either.

Comment: @Voo Dude, this is a *java* question (see question tags)... C is irrelevant.

Comment: @Bohemian Ever heard of this pesky technology called [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JNI)? You know the one that actually has a type called `jstring` which Java itself doesn't have, is used for all kinds of native things in Java and written in **c**?

Comment: @Bohemian: looking at the edit, I realize that this question didn't have the jni tag when it was posted - but this does indeed appear to be JNI in C.

Comment: @Bohemian this is C code, not Java code. The presence of 'jstring' is sufficient to establish that. The JVM has nothing to do with how it executes.